# How does one get the ttf-dejavu fonts to show up in xlsfonts for use in rxvt?

Tags: 10.04, fonts

I installed the [`ttf-dejavu`](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/) package and can use the fonts in [`gnome-terminal`](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/). However, I want to use them in [`rxvt`](http://www.rxvt.org/), but they do not show up with [`xlsfonts`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xfree86.org%2Fcurrent%2Fxlsfonts.1.html&rct=j&q=xlsfonts&ei=qdP2TKLZM8L_lge9z_2UBg&usg=AFQjCNE9iw41OwPFKr52bs6dZCJ4vgK2UA) and `rxvt` reports "can't load font" when I try to use "DejaVu Sans Mono" in `.Xdefaults`. I found this [confirmed bug (#574409)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttf-dejavu/+bug/574409), but there is no workaround.

Comment: xlsfonts doesn't list any of the fonts I use in urxvt (Monaco and Mensch), yet they're available to me. It seems to be kind of a crap-shoot. Can we see your .Xdefaults?

Comment: I was using rxvt. After switching to urxvt everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround more than a literal solution to the question. I switch to urxvt (i.e. rxvt-unicode) and the following .Xdefaults lines work just fine. A similar configuration for regular rxvt could not locate the same font.

```
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:antialias=true:pixelsize=14
URxvt.boldFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:style=bold:antialias=true:pixelsize=14
```